# XPages Properties Editor

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xsp

I have updated version 8.5.3 to 9.0.1 of the notes, and in xPages Properties has the field minimum supported release, in the version update I did not change the checked option, does anyone know what the impact of this field in the application?

[configuration location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Uvz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a feature in XPages that is higher than the version you have entered you will get a warning when you build the application.

Note this does not affect code, ie, if you use a new Java 1.8 feature that is in Feature Pack 10 it will not warn you that your Java code will not work if it runs on a down level server.

Answer (score 0):

The Minimum Supported Release can be set to the default:

> Minimum release required by the XPage features used.

You may optionally choose the minimum sorted release for a specific version of Notes client/server.

I do not select anything else, just use the default.